# Flagging a deleted comment will tell you that that comment no longer exists

Tags: feature-request, comments, flags

If you flag a comment that happens to have been deleted before you flagged it (probably because several other people have flagged it) then a red box is displayed that states that that comment no longer exists. Ordinarily flagging a comment will not display anything.

I don't think that flagging a comment that doesn't exist is so significant that I should see a big error box when it happens. This is made even worse by the fact that **I can't do anything about it!**

If you feel like you have to display something to me when I try to flag an offensive, spammy or abusive comment that doesn't exist anymore, then please don't make it look like I've done something wrong. Make it something that is happy and cheerful because this one little piece of offensiveness, spam or abuse is no longer a part of this world.

Edit: Since this feature is probably behaving as designed I've retagged the post as a feature-request.

Answer (score 11):

You got an error message telling you that an error occurred...when an error occurred (trying to delete something that no longer exists).

If this is not by-design, I don't know what is.

Answer (score 5):

I see nothing wrong with letting you know that the comment no longer exists.

You know you didn't do anything wrong, what makes you think you did?  The red box appears all of the time.  I appreciate the consistency.

Answer (score 5):

The big red boxes don't mean that you've done something wrong.

Many things on SO use those big red boxes.  If you downvote a question, you get a big box advising you to leave a comment.

Certainly downvoting is not something *wrong* so why would you think the same of this feature?

If you try to vote on two comments within 5 seconds, you get the red box.  if you try to comment twice within 30 seconds, you get the box, basically advising you that it ignored what you just did.

If you flag a question/answer, you get the big red box.

Comment: Red means "look at me!" not "shame on you!"  "Shame on you!" is chartreuse, "stop doing that!" is periwinkle, and "this is your final warning" is papaya whip.

Comment: Red means "Stop"... **Hammer Time!**

Comment: @TheTXI: YOU ARE WHITE.

Comment: @Rich B: Which is why he's making that reference about 20 years too late.

Comment: Would you rather that we... Stop, Collaborate and Listen?

Comment: @devinb: Somewhere, a fairy is dying... because I'm punching it in the face repeatedly.

Answer (score 5):

The red box does not mean that you did something in error. The Red Box simply means that there is a message that the user should know about.

Much like a JavaScript alert. It is simply for information, do not be alarmed. Please continue your days.

We apologize for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 2):

What error? What inconvenience?

When I flag something because it upsets me, I am happy to learn that it is no longer there so I don't have to be upset anymore.